# Setting source for HTML frame in Print Composer using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, html

I have defined an HTML Frame in my composer using:

```
html_frame = composition.getComposerItemById('html_frame')
```

How can I set its source using PyQGIS?

---

[image]

Comment: using `drawText` method https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsComposerItem.html

Comment: @FranciscoRaga - Thanks for the link although I am still unsure how to set the text. I tested with `html_frame.drawText(QPainter(), 1, 1,  '"<b>Example</b>"', QFont())` after setting the imports but still nothing.

Comment: Check this code https://github.com/shawnmcarter/nohrsc_scripts/blob/fa6550bb58f2a7e3dc6a39c707502b980e0a47ec/ATO.py#L348, and remeber call `refreshItems()`after set text

Comment: added sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a sample code using a label and html:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QFont

composition = iface.activeComposers()[0].composition()
html_frame = composition.getComposerItemById('html')
composer_html = html_frame.multiFrame()
label = composition.getComposerItemById('label')

#Html Example
output_html = "<b>Example! From Code 2</b>"
composer_html.setHtml(output_html)
composer_html.loadHtml()

#Label Example
label.setText("Hello, World! From Code")
label.setFont(QFont("Cambria",15, QFont.Bold))
label.adjustSizeToText()

composition.refreshItems()
```

But if you want only change Html Frame only is necessary this 6 lines:

```
#Html Example
composition = iface.activeComposers()[0].composition()
html_frame = composition.getComposerItemById('html')
composer_html = html_frame.multiFrame()
output_html = "<b>Example! From Code</b>"
composer_html.setHtml(output_html)
composer_html.loadHtml()
```

regards

Comment: Absolutely perfect! I also included `composer_html.setContentMode(1)` which sets the _HTML Source_ parameter to `Source` instead of the default `URL` (which was needed for my case as I am creating an HTML frame from scratch). Many thanks =)